# How to add a row of observed confidence interval above meta-analysis in R

Tags: r

I am new to meta-analysis and was hoping to see some advice. I was wondering if there is an approach in adding a 90% CI line for observed above the meta-analysis. Sample code are provided below. I would really appreciate your help.

```
install.packages("meta")

library("meta")

abc <- structure(list(Study = c("Study 1", "Study 2", "Study 3", "Study 4", 
                                "Study 5", "Study 6", "Study 7", "Study 8", 
                                "Study 9", "Study 10", "Study 11", "Study 12",
                                "Study 13", "Study 14", "Study 15", "Study 16"), 
                      event.e = c(1L, 4L, 6L, 20L, 69L, 22L, 19L, 26L, 13L, 2L, 
                                  7L, 2L, 29L, 6L, 11L, 4L), n.e = c(12L, 21L, 43L, 83L, 373L, 
                                                                     219L, 164L, 264L, 102L, 14L, 53L, 60L, 172L, 55L, 49L, 14L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))


summary(abc) #For the summary of the dataset.

def <- metaprop(event = event.e, 
                n= n.e, 
                data=abc,
                studlab = Study,
                sm="Plogit",
                level = 0.95,
                comb.fixed=TRUE, comb.random=TRUE,
                hakn=F,
                method.tau="DL")


forest(def)
From https://rpubs.com/yasiranwar/meta-in-r-1
```

Here is the sample 90% CI of observed I would like to include above the meta-analysis

```
zyx <- structure(list(Median = c(0.15), 
                      Min = c(0.1), Max = c(0.2)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

So that it would look like this below:

[image]

I was hoping to add what's enclosed in Red, listed as ZYX. If there is an another package to use, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Please save the RStudio tag for questions where RStudio is part of the problem - like if your code doesn't work in RStudio but does work on the command line.